# Code completion is not working in callback

Tags: javascript, callback, closures, webstorm, code-completion

I'm trying to make my Code Completion work in callback, in this example code completion ignores object properties

```
const arr = [{hex: 'ad0', blow: 123}];

const implementer = (currentArray, callback) => {
    function test(val) {
        callback(val);
    }

    return test(currentArray[0]);
};

implementer(arr, (element) => {
    console.log(element);
});
```

So when I press ctrl+space at dot in `element.`, nothing appears. I've attached a sceenshot,[image] thus you undestand what I'am trying to implement.

Comment: Can you show us how `iterate` is implemented? Are you using type signatures (jsdoc, typescript, flow)?

Comment: @Bergi, Sorry, I erased `iterate` function, because it was hardcoded badly and didn't solve what I wanted. In code example I'm not using any type signatures.

Comment: Can you explain how in `Array.from` callback undestands that's parament is a element passed from given array?

Comment: You haven't even stated which IDE you are using and how its code completion works, so no I cannot explain that. But I would assume that it uses a type inference system with generics.

Comment: I'm using Webstorm and it's native Code Completion